# SystemD uses 100% of CPU 5 minutes after my user's login

Tags: systemd

Many times in the past day, my laptop has overheated and shut off after being on for just a few minutes. The second of these times, I was using `top` for something and I was horrified to see `systemd` and `systemd-journal` and a few other processes like `dbus message bus` using `100%+` of a core *each*.

from a small amount of googling the problem seems to be like these two:

- https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61191
- http://bugs.rosalinux.ru/show_bug.cgi?id=1317

and a lot of the rest of [these google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=systemd+using+100%25+of+cpu) have information pertaining to my problem but no real solution, just ancient bugfixes which are surely in upstream already.

This is not a one time thing, it happens after 5 minutes of uptime, every time.

***Edit:*** I logged in to a virtual TTY (Ctrl-Alt-F1) as root and the problem hasn't happened so far. What could possibly be related to my user's login?

What can I do to prevent this sort of fault? I recently accidentally uninstalled a lot of packages but I fixed the problems and everything works fine as before.

---

[`systemctl -al`](http://pastebin.com/cbJUZJih).

[`journalctl | tail -n400`](http://pastebin.com/DrhALC8H).

---

Here are some examples of this happening *again* (right now):

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                      
    1 root      20   0  185480   6080   3900 R 100.0  0.1   1:27.54 systemd                                                                                                                      
  699 message+  20   0   44316   5148   3500 R  93.7  0.1   1:25.50 dbus-daemon                                                                                                                  
  300 root      20   0   34716   4400   3964 R  56.2  0.1   0:49.01 systemd-journal                                                                                                              
  848 syslog    20   0  256372   4288   2648 S  43.7  0.1   0:33.05 rsyslogd                                                                                                                     
  835 root      20   0   28628   3204   2816 R  18.7  0.1   0:22.72 systemd-logind
```

or

```
    1 root      20   0  186928   7632   3988 R  99.9  0.1   5:37.49 systemd                                                         
  806 message+  20   0   44212   5216   3540 R  99.6  0.1   5:34.16 dbus-daemon                                                     
  298 root      20   0   34712   6824   6360 R  53.1  0.1   3:05.28 systemd-journal
```

or

```
    1 root      20   0  186928   7632   3988 R 100.0  0.1   6:29.31 systemd                                                         
  298 root      20   0   34712   7784   7320 R  50.8  0.1   3:33.11 systemd-journal                                                 
 8165 root      20   0   90668  23408  12636 R  27.7  0.4   0:00.84 debtags                                                         
  789 root      20   0   28636   3156   2780 S  21.8  0.1   1:29.49 systemd-logind
```

---

A pretty picture that I'm not gonna bother trimming (I'm including this for the rest of `top`'s status):

[image]

Comment: that log is pure madness... how is your ram when that happens?

Comment: Memory usage is pretty normal, though I'll check, and `memtest` seems to show my RAM's not damaged