# Why does my user's login cause systemd to use up a CPU?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

Recently I asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254490/) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/719323/) about `systemd` and a few related processes using `100%` CPU just 5 minutes after every boot.

I have a quadcore Intel processor, each core has two virtual cores for a total of 8 CPU cores. Three or more of these being at 100%+ utilisation causes problems for my ancient laptop, namely overheating, and to preserve itself it powers off under such temperatures.

However, I noticed the system runs totally normally until a few minutes after *I -- my user* -- logs in - only then does `systemd` go haywire, and logging out does not stop it.

What's causing this? What about my user's login specifically would cause this?

It only happens when my account, `cat`, logs in: not the guest session, not `root` in a TTY or graphical session -- I logged in to a virtual TTY (Ctrl-Alt-F1) as `root` and the problem hasn't happened so far.

from a small amount of googling the problem seems to be like these two:

- [FreeDesktop - systemd-journald eats 100% CPU](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61191)
- [ROSA Linux - systemd occupies 100% utilization of CPU](http://bugs.rosalinux.ru/show_bug.cgi?id=1317)

and a lot of the rest of [these google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=systemd+using+100%25+of+cpu) have information pertaining to my problem but no real solution, just ancient bugfixes which are surely in upstream already.

This is not a one time thing, it's 5 or fewer minutes after logging in as myself, every time.

What's going on with `systemd` after I log in?

---

Incidentally, this is Ubuntu 15.10 (functionally Debian), and all my packages are up to date. Some logs / examples:

---

[`systemctl -al`](http://pastebin.com/cbJUZJih). (long)

[`journalctl | tail -n400`](http://pastebin.com/DrhALC8H). (less long, but long)

---

Here are some examples of this happening *again* (right now):

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                      
    1 root      20   0  185480   6080   3900 R 100.0  0.1   1:27.54 systemd                                                                                                                      
  699 message+  20   0   44316   5148   3500 R  93.7  0.1   1:25.50 dbus-daemon                                                                                                                  
  300 root      20   0   34716   4400   3964 R  56.2  0.1   0:49.01 systemd-journal                                                                                                              
  848 syslog    20   0  256372   4288   2648 S  43.7  0.1   0:33.05 rsyslogd                                                                                                                     
  835 root      20   0   28628   3204   2816 R  18.7  0.1   0:22.72 systemd-logind
```

or

```
    1 root      20   0  186928   7632   3988 R  99.9  0.1   5:37.49 systemd                                                         
  806 message+  20   0   44212   5216   3540 R  99.6  0.1   5:34.16 dbus-daemon                                                     
  298 root      20   0   34712   6824   6360 R  53.1  0.1   3:05.28 systemd-journal
```

or

```
    1 root      20   0  186928   7632   3988 R 100.0  0.1   6:29.31 systemd                                                         
  298 root      20   0   34712   7784   7320 R  50.8  0.1   3:33.11 systemd-journal                                                 
 8165 root      20   0   90668  23408  12636 R  27.7  0.4   0:00.84 debtags                                                         
  789 root      20   0   28636   3156   2780 S  21.8  0.1   1:29.49 systemd-logind
```

---

A pretty picture:

[image]

Comment: If you'd like help, please provide as much information as you can(and as you think is needed) in *this single post*.

Comment: Yeah asking for help then saying we need to go through their previous posts to get all the information they know we need is kind of a dick move.

Comment: @MatthewRock Okay, I originally didn't have a lot of time to type this out before my computer overheated, but fair point. At least it's getting attention...

Comment: @Bratchley I've edited my question

Comment: @MatthewRock do you want me to inline the pastebins? They're in pastebin for a reason...

Comment: @tac Generally, the site's philosophy is that everything that's related to the question/answers should be in the question/answer itself - we prefer to rely on SE servers than on external ones; paste and hosting services come and go, rendering many links invalid. Pasting text here, while appearing ugly, saves it from this risk. Plus, it spares clicks.

Comment: Have you tried unmasking the units it's talking about in the journal? The CPU usage is probably due to systemd continually trying to (re)start services that are failing due to dependencies. Not sure why one would mask though services, tbh.

Comment: @MatthewRock As I was saying, they're in pastebin for a reason. ***"Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 78916"***

Comment: @Bratchley I haven't masked anything :o

Comment: Regardless of how they got like that you might try to see if unmasking fixes your issue. For the other thing, the "in the body of the post" is the rule of thumb. For data that long, putting it into the question's body is just impractical.

Comment: @tac I said *generally*.  If your paste is huge, then you don't have other choice, do you?

Comment: What about another regular (non-guest, non-root), freshly created user account?

Comment: Is putting a trace on `systemd` an option? `strace` or whatever. If this happens predictably, it should be possible to see what `systemd` is doing.

Comment: On the one hand you write that the system runs normally until you login, on the other hand that after 5 minutes of uptime this happens. This is contradictory, i.e. what happens if you don't login? Are you using wireless that is only enabled by logging in?

Comment: @Anthon Sorry it was unclear, that should imply 5 minutes of logged-in uptime, not uptime in general

Comment: @FaheemMitha I don't know how to do that...? When I boot my computer, `systemd` starts as the init service, and you can't invoke `strace` on a currently running process... can you?

Comment: @Bratchley How would I go about unmasking things?

Comment: @cat you just us the `systemctl unmask` command on any of the units units listed in the `journalctl` output.

Comment: @cat I think you can run strace to a currently running process. See e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482076/how-does-strace-connect-to-an-already-running-process. If you can't figure out how to do this, ask here.